# How to open DBF file in DBeaver with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, dbf, dbase, dbeaver

I'm not sure why I can't connect to .DBF files using DBeaver with the built in JDBC driver for "Flat Tiles (CSV/DBF).

I have a share drive with dozens of DBF files on it. I create the connections as shown in the attached images, but when I connect to the source I have two issues. I've included the steps I follow and the error that I get.

Does anyone have experience connecting to DBF files with JDBC and or using the DBeaver tool that might help me here?

I did download that DANS-DBF library JAR from GitHub but I am not sure how I can use it in this situation. I noticed on [this site](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/doc.html) it says

> CsvJdbc requires Java version 1.6, or later. For reading DBF files, DANS DBF Library must be downloaded and included in the CLASSPATH.

But I'm not sure how I can add it to DBeaver projects. They don't use build paths like an actual java project.

(I know I can open them in excel, but I prefer this tool for data queries).

**I create the database**
[image]

**I select the build in CSV DBF connection type.**
[image]

**The driver properties only had .CSV I tried it with this setting, and when it didn't work, I changed it to .dbf and it still didn't work**
[image]

**I can connect to this folder fine, and i know there are plenty of DBF files in it.**
[image]

**Settings FYI.**
[image]

**When I try to open the one DBF file that appears I get an error message.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may add screen with Tab with "Driver properties".

Comment: It's already there. 3rd image.

Comment: You added driver jdbc in configuration.

Comment: Added 2 screenshots, hope that's what you mean.

Comment: This library in not a stable version may use stable version driver jdbc.

Comment: Are you able to be more specific? Could you provide information on where a more stable version would be and why this one is not appropriate to use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: dans-dbf-lib-1.0.0-beta-10.jar - is beta version is may not work (not tested in production environment).

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for breathing life into this year and a half old post but I had the same problem and this was the first link on google.

After much research and fiddling I got DBeaver to open a .dbf flat file using most of the settings you already described.

The CSV/DBF JDBC Driver to open dbf files requires DANS DBF as you mentioned and requires its addition to the CLASS PATH.  There was limited information on that process and I have found no easy way to modify that in Dbeaver.  I also looked through a few other JDBC that supposedly opened xBASE files such as HXTT but they weren't free which was a deal breaker for my use.

I did however get it to work by placing the DANS DBF jar file in the same directory with the csv JDBC driver.  It had no trouble finding it as a dependency and ran like a charm.

So for anyone who is looking to do this.

- In DBeaver open the driver manager and select the csv flat file
- download the driver if needed.
- download DANS DBF from souce forge
  http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net
- add that file to the driver and make sure you put it in the same directory as the csvjdbc driver.  It should be in your user folder .dbeaver-drivers. if you click the driver file and the information button it should give you the filepath.
- Then add the DANS DBF file to the driver manager
- Make sure you change the file filter type to .dbf as you did otherwise it will hide all .dbf files.
- Make a new connction and you are good to go!

a few things to note. I found that the file type extension is case sensitive so if you filter by .dbf then .DBF will not show up in the connection.  A few people commented that the JDBC driver doesn't like spaces in filenames and it is a read only driver with a few quirks.

Comment: Delete links in the driver properties interface to existing driver files and add each .jar individually. Be sure to delete existing connection and make new one.

Comment: I'm sorry to nescroposting this, but i'm having trouble with this error. I followed all the steps, removed the drivers and put them back manually. I've added the path on the PATH enviroment variables, but still getting the error. What am I missing

Comment: Thats ok, however; I gave up on DBeaver a while ago.  if I remember correctly, the biggest thing I was missing was the flat file reader CSV driver used dans dbf library and it wasn't pre bundled.  So I basically added it manually and it just seemed to work.  I will say the .dbf file type is case sensitive so if you have.DBF and specify .dbf the driver won't find them.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently and wanted to share, if you're still having problems of DBeaver stating it cant find Field or getRecordCount, etc.  Serphentelm mentioned following the steps and still getting an error.  I found that the JAR file from sourceforge is the source, NOT the compiled .class files.

I had to build the jar myself.  For those needing it, I put it here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=59469996816520223299

I placed that in the csvjdbc folder mentioned above, then just did "Add File" from the Edit Driver page in DBeaver to add the jar.

Answer (score 0):

For DBeaver 2.22.1:

- download dans-dbf-lib-1.0.0-beta-10.jar (e.g. from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dans-dbf-lib/files/dans-dbf-lib/beta-10/))
- in Drivers location, Local folder (in Windows: C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers) create the \drivers\dbf directory. NB 'drivers' must be created under drivers, so ...\DBeaverData\drivers\drivers\...
- put dans-dbf-lib-1.0.0-beta-10.jar in this folder
- now you can create a new connection using the Embedded/DBF driver